# Border longer then image in footer

Tags: html, css, image, border, footer

I am trying to add an image in my footer section for a client and for some reason the border to the right is longer then the others, and also longer them the image itself. I have tried adding "border: none;" to the image but something is still overriding it. I don't care if the border to the right of the image is gone, or if it is shortened. I just need some help.

Here is a link to a picture of the problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JFAP.jpg

```
<div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="help">
                <div class="copyright alignleft">
                    <p>©2013<a href="index.html">Infotek-Soultions</a></p>
                    <a href="Default.html"><img src="images/gear.png" width="20" height="21" alt="Tools" style="border:none;"/></a>
                    <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
                    <a href="Default.html">Resources</a>
                    <a href="Default.html">Client Portal</a>

                </div> <!-- END copyright -->
```

This is my CSS file

```
.copyright p{
font-family: 'sansationregular';
color:#d8d8d8;
font-size: 12px;
float:left;
margin:0;
} 
.copyright{
margin-top:5px;
}
.copyright a{
font-family: 'sansationregular';
color:#d8d8d8;
font-size: 12px;
float:right;
text-decoration: none;
border-right:1px solid #d8d8d8;
padding:0 10px;
 }
.copyright a:hover{
color:#d8d8d8;
opacity: 0.6;
 }
.copyright img{
border: none;
 }
```

Please help if possible. If you need me to provide anything else, I can. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please demo the issue in JSFiddle. You should be aware that you are adding the border to the `a` tags so removing if from the image will have no effect.

Comment: I am trying to add a JSFiddle, but the image isn't showing up other then a small box

Comment: You can try, `.copyright a:last-child { border-right: 0; }`

Comment: You will have to have the image hosted online (perhaps photobucket.com) or use an image placeholder service like lorempixel.com

Comment: Curiously the HTML provided does not seem to match the image given.

Comment: match what image given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the image is making the anchor element taller.

here is a fix to remove the border:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpjlE

HTML:

```
 <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="help">
            <div class="copyright alignleft">
                <p>©2013<a href="index.html">Infotek-Soultions</a></p>

              <a href="Default.html" class="no-border"><img src="images/gear.png" width="20" height="21" alt="Tools"/>
              </a>

              <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
                <a href="Default.html">Resources</a>
                <a href="Default.html">Client Portal</a>

            </div> <!-- END copyright -->
```

CSS:

```
 .copyright p{
```

font-family: 'sansationregular';
color:#d8d8d8;
font-size: 12px;
float:left;
margin:0;
} 
.copyright{
margin-top:5px;
}
.copyright a{
font-family: 'sansationregular';
color:#d8d8d8;
font-size: 12px;
float:right;
text-decoration: none;
border-right:1px solid #d8d8d8;
padding:0 10px;
 }
.copyright a:hover{
color:#d8d8d8;
opacity: 0.6;
 }

.copyright> a > img{
  height:100%;
  float:right;
}

.copyright > a.no-border{
  border:none;
}